# Android: How to create a reusable class for several layout screens to Enable/Disable Wifi Programmatically

Tags: android, class, wifi, code-reuse

I want to create a *reusable class* for several layout screens to Enable/Disable Wifi Programmatically and other tasks . Below is my code. But getSystemService do not work without extends Activity. So what is the best way to do this and similar things?

```
public void WifiOn(Context context){
     WifiManager mainWifiObj ;
     mainWifiObj = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
     mainWifiObj.setWifiEnabled(true);

    }

 public void WifiOff(Context context){
     WifiManager mainWifiObj ;
     mainWifiObj = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
     mainWifiObj.setWifiEnabled(false);

    }
```

Comment: just put conet.getsystemservice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this,

```
public void WifiOn(Context context) {
        WifiManager mainWifiObj;
        mainWifiObj = (WifiManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        mainWifiObj.setWifiEnabled(true);

    }

    public void WifiOff(Context context) {
        WifiManager mainWifiObj;
        mainWifiObj = (WifiManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        mainWifiObj.setWifiEnabled(false);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it `context.getSystemService()`.  That will work anywhere